# Outlook Add-in for Android :Exception trying to access userProfile. Elevated Permission required to access protected members of Javascript API-Office

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

We have noticed that when we try to access Office.context.mailbox.userProfile in order to get the Logged in user email address and display name, we are getting an exception and the app doesn't load.
The Add-in works properly on :

- Web client Windows and Mac
- Desktop platform app Windows and Mac
- iOS Outlook Mobile app

The office documentation mentions, userProfile is accessible for [ API set: Mailbox 1.0 ]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.userprofile?view=office-js

We are targeting the API Version 1.3, which supports Outlook for Android.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets?view=office-js

It used to work on Android as well till a week before. But suddenly we are seeing this error.

> Error : Elevated Permissions is required to access Protected members
>   of the Javascript API for office.

[Failed to load user profile data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAfo1.png)

We tried to query the userProfile on console using 
window.Office.context.mailbox.userProfile
It returns the same Error.
[Error when query userprofile on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZzL3.png)

Also, if we query window.Office.context.mailbox
and check the permissions on the userProfile object, it shows Permissions 0.
[Permissions 0 for userProfile object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKz0h.png)

What could be the issue here ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for inconvenience, This issue has been fixed few days ago, Soon it will start working again as solution will be included in production build.
Issue was at framework side of Android Outlook Add-ins. It was providing message context with wrong permission.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21079967)

Comment: We own this module in Microsoft Outlook Team. We can not provide internal implementation details, So we are just giving to the point answer that we have fixed it on f/w side.

Comment: It is fixed and should be available in prod in 2 weeks.