# How can I get the email body with a mobile Add-In

Tags: outlook-addin

I'm working on a mobile extension point for my Add-In.

I want to get the HTML contents of an email, from a taskpane.

On the desktop version of the Add-In, I call **Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync()** from the taskpane javascript file, which works fine.

However, on the outlook mobile app for android, **Office.context.mailbox.item.body** is an empty object. **Office.context.mailbox.item** seems to have all the context about the conversation but not about the actual email.

How can I get the HTML body of the email from mobile?

Comment: Thanks for raising it. we are working towards fixing it.

Comment: Further to question, I've noticed that I'm getting the error message: *Elevated permission is required to access protected members of the JavaScript API for Office* from a similar call. I think this question may be a duplicate of *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697160/outlook-add-in-for-android-exception-trying-to-access-userprofile-elevated-per*

Answer (score 0):

For accessing body on Outlook Android, you will have to use Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(). Please find same snippet below:

```js
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync("text",
 function (asyncResult) {
  if (asyncResult.status == "failed") {
   console.log("Action failed with error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
  } else {
   console.log(asyncResult.value);
  }
 }
);
```